# Appcelerator , can not change tabsBackgroundColor in android

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

The attribute tabsBackgroundColor in tagGroup tag not working on android

```
  <TabGroup tabsBackgroundColor="#a466a3">
```

and backgroundColor not working too , although it is written in the documentation 
 http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to modify your theme file / create a custom android theme to set the appearance of of your tabs. 
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Themes

If you read that you'll see how to add and setup a custom theme to override the base theme that Titanium gives you.

The XML property you'll want to modify for the background colour is `actionBarTabStyle`

A helpful but old tool that you can use to auto generate this is https://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

Comment: Thanks @Michael , could you give me an answer for this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37902939?noredirect=1)